# How does rails find the column alias in select statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails' active record querying section, there is one example for column alias. Like `a = Article.select("id, sum(1) as cnt").group("id")`. Then you could get the `cnt` by `a.first.cnt`. However, I could not find `cnt` in following methods:

- `a.first.singleton_methods`
- `a.first.methods.grep(/cnt/)`
- `a.first.instance_variables`

Could I know where I could find the `cnt` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias will be added as an attribute for the record. If you use  `attributes` in one of the results then you'll see it there, like:

```
Article.select('id, sum(1) as cnt').group('id').first.attributes
# => {"id"=>1, "cnt"=>1}
```

In that similar way you can access to it:

```
Article.select('id, sum(1) as cnt').group('id').first.cnt
# => 1

Article.select('id, sum(1) as cnt').group('id').first[:cnt]
# => 1
```